# How to block user to access some Sharepoint 3.0 sites

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have Sharepoint 3.0 deployed on a Windows 2008 server platform. My issue is quite simple for now but I still can't figure it out.

I have added the domain admin group from AD. So all of us can access any site that I've created. My issue is that I created a Sharepoint test user in AD and this one can also access every sites on sharepoint. The only AD group linked to this user is Domain Users.

Is anybody has a tutorial or knows how to prevent or block some groups/users to access our IT and Dev sites?

Regards,
David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Sharepoint expert, it's been awhile since I've worked on Sharepoint, and I don't have a Sharepoint server handy but I think I'm on track with this:

As far as the test user having access to all the Sharepoint sites, If I'm not mistaken, Sharepoint sites inherit permissions from the parent so you have to go to each site and set specific permissions for those sites that you don't want the test user to access.

So all of your users except for the test user are domain admins? If so, that's not good.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I finally figured out with the persmissions on each specific site.

Thanks a bunch!
David.

Comment: Happy to help and glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fact that every user seems to be domain admin, that strikes me as not good at all :-D.